# Order of execution of function calls within a line - undefined?

Tags: c++, c

p.77 K&R C says the output of the following program is undefined, but current version of Xcode gives no warning. Is it still undefined in current standard? What about in C++? Bonus points for similar program in Java and C#.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int my_m()
{
    static int n = 0;
    static int m[] = { 42, 57 };
    return n++ % 2 == 0 ? m[0] : m[1];
}
int main()
{
    printf("%d" , my_m() - my_m());

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The order of evaluation is unspecified.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The result isn't actually undefined, just unspecified.

The difference is that undefined behavior means *anything* can happen, including behavior that seems to be entirely unrelated to anything in the program at all. The classic line is that it "makes demons fly out of your nose."

Unspecified means that you have no way of knowing *which* call of `my_m` will be evaluated first and which will be evaluated second, *but* it will be<sup>1</sup> one invocation and then the other. One call will start and run to completion then the other call will start and run to completion--the two won't be interleaved or anything like that. The only thing that's unpredictable is the *order* in which the two calls are made (and yes, under current C and C++ standards, the order is still 100% unpredictable).

In both C# and Java the order of evaluation is specified as left to right.

---

<sup>1. Or at least it'll act as if it did. Both C and C++ follow what's usually called the "as if rule" that allows a compiler to do things differently as long as it does so in a way that maintains the specified externally visible behavior.</sup>

Comment: Thanks for terminology clarification (K&R says order is "not defined" - I know it's really old).

Comment: Technically, it's possible that both invocations happen at the same time as long as the compiler ensures that the observable side effects are identical to what you would see if they happened one after the other (in either order).

Comment: *Both* editions of K&R predate the ANSI standard of 1989, which defined these terms. The second revised edition was written when the standard was approaching its final draft but not all the repercussions of the phrasing were known at that time.

Answer (score 3):

A compiler won't warn you about all undefined programs. In the following line:

```
printf("%d" , my_m() - my_m());
```

the order of the calls `my_m()` is unspecified. The compiler might decide to call either the first one or the second one first. Since the function returns `42` on the first call and `57` on the second call the result is either `42 - 57` or `57 - 42`.

Edit: I missed the difference between undefined and unspecified, see Jerry Coffins answer for details about that.